# PHP Desktop app with Google Cast extension?

Tags: php, desktop, google-cast, chromium-embedded

I'm looking to create an app with [PHP Desktop](http://code.google.com/p/phpdesktop/). I plan to use the [Chromium Embedded Framework version](http://code.google.com/p/phpdesktop/wiki/DownloadChrome). I want to allow users to use my Chromecast app with it. Is there a way to use the [Google Cast extension](http://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-cast/boadgeojelhgndaghljhdicfkmllpafd) in this scenario? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Chromium Embedded Framework does not support Google Chrome extensions. Plugins (NPAPI/PPAPI) are supported. Chrome cast is an extension, so unfortunately it won't work.

Comment: Is there any way to port the extension? Either to a plugin or to inject the scripts? Thanks!

Comment: @GiantDuck Yes, that's feasible. Chrome extensions are written in javascript. The amount of work when porting depends on an extension.

Comment: Are you able to look at the source to see if it's easily possible? TYSM!